# Adding photo category to php code?

Tags: php, mysql

I was able to develop a code in enabling users to freely upload images, while the pictures would be stored to the MySql database. But I also would like to add to the php and mysql code image categories where before uploading the image, users can select from ether category- All, People, Cities, Nature and Others then click submit. How do I add that to my php code and mysql table? See my original code below:

```
<?php

$dbCnn = mysql_connect('', '', '');

mysql_select_db('', $dbCnn);

if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
    $insStr = "INSERT INTO imagedata(id, image) VALUES ('', '{$image}')";
    mysql_query($insStr);
}
```

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and are likely to be removed in the next major release. Instead, switch to either `MySQLi` or `PDO`, both are easy to get a grasp of with great examples in the docs.

Comment: There are a lot of things wrong with your code posted. As the person before me said mysql_* is deprecated. You are storing images directly in your database which will slow it down faster than it has to. I would recommend storing links to the images in the database and storing the images on a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store images in database because it's useless. Instead of this, store in database only path to file and file save on server.
So...

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<select name="category">
<option>Nature</opton>
<option>People</option
</select>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['category']) && isset($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])){
//mysql connect etc
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], path/where/to/save/file);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('{$_FILES['file']['name']}', '{$_POST['category']}')");
}
```

Comment: You would want to advise that the person does validity checks on the $_POST variables before inserting them into the database. You're leaving the database open for SQL injection in the posted code

Comment: Yes I know and I also reccomend to use PDO or MySQLi and bind params.

Comment: Thanks much, this has been of great help and will consider your suggestions on PDO and MySQLI. I have a part two to the question. Once the user selects the category, how do they search for it and find it in that particular category that was selected?

Comment: Simply mysql query with WHERE condition